# Error: UPGRADE FAILED: pre-upgrade hooks failed: timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-jobs

I am testing a pre-upgrade hook which just has a bash script that prints a string and sleep for 10 mins. When I run helm upgrade, it ran for some time and exited with the error in the title. I used kubectl to check the job and it was still running. Any idea on how to get rid of the error?

Thanks

The script in the container that the job runs:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Sleeping for testing..."
sleep 600
```

Answer (score 14):

Use `--timeout` to your helm command to set your required timeout, the default timeout is `5m0s`.

```
$ helm install <name> <chart> --timeout 10m30s
```

> `--timeout`: A value in seconds to wait for Kubernetes commands to complete. This defaults to 5m0s (5 minutes).

Helm documentation: https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#helpful-options-for-installupgraderollback

Comment: Thank you! Let me try it. I thought there could be a default timeout but didn't find it

Comment: It shows `Error: Unit missing in timeout argument`. If that's the case, use `--timeout 700s`

Comment: You need to use in this format:  `--timeout 10m30s`.